# Collection View in TableView Show item [VGS.CustumCell collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a viewController there are collection and tableview and tableview cell their is another collection view . if we not use tableview code my first colletion work fine but when we use tableview .My application became crash and show error

```
 [VGS.CustumCell collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .
```

Please help I am newer in iOS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
             dayArray = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"]
            let identifier = "TimeViewCell"
            collection.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TimeViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            self.timetableTableview.estimatedRowHeight = 79
            self.timetableTableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

            self.timetableTableview.setNeedsLayout()
            self.timetableTableview.layoutIfNeeded()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


    extension TimeTableController : UICollectionViewDelegate {
        func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 6
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if collectionView.tag == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TimeViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeViewCell
               cell.daylabel.text = dayArray[indexPath.row] as? String
            if (indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.firstColor()
            } else if (indexPath.row == 1){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondfColor()
            }else if (indexPath.row == 2){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.thirdColor()
            }else if (indexPath.row == 3){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.fourthColor()
            }else if (indexPath.row == 4){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.fifthColor()
            }else if (indexPath.row == 5){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.sixthColor()
            }

                   return cell
            } else {
              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Timetable", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Timetable
               return cell

    }
    }
    }
    extension TimeTableController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



         func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }


         func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let identifier = "CustumCell"
            var cell: CustumCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustumCell
            if cell == nil {
                var nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustumCell", owner: self, options: nil)

                cell = nib[7] as? CustumCell
                let identifier = "Timetable"
                cell.timecollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Timetable", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)

            }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
            return cell
        }

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue.  My problem was that I hooked up the delegate and datasource both on the storyboard and in my viewDidLoad.  This cancels it out.  I first tried deleting my delegate & data source connections from my viewController file, but it still wasn't displaying the contents in my IBOutlets.  But when I did vice versa, it did the trick.  Make sure you declare it in one or the other.

My solution:

1. [Disconnect via storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtcQ2.png)
2. Declare datasource and delegate in your view controller's viewDidLoad.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      mainCategoryCollectionView.delegate = self
      mainCategoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the dataSource for the `collectionView`. Add it to the extension, where you are already assigning the delegate.

```
extension TimeTableController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

And do not forget declare the required functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}
```

Comment: Sir I am declared this seperately

Comment: can you show that piece of code? Also, why are you declaring than `dataSource` functions in the delegate?